# Try to map through an enum in TS with Object.entries<T>(Enum).map(), but only works with string based enums?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, mapping

I'm building a react form where a user has to select some options for a job, where the options are each represented by enums.  Given what I have to accomplish, some of these enums are based on strings,  and others are number based.

Example,  string based

```
export enum ProjectType {      
    Construction = 'Construction',        
    Drilling = 'Drilling',      
    Completions = 'Completions',     
    Workover = 'Workover / Abandonment',       
    Water = 'Water Sourcing',       
    FracSatellite = 'Satellite Frac Monitoring',
    FracDesign = 'Frac Engineering & Design'
}
```

and then number based

```
export enum ProjectStatus {
    AllProjects = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Operational = 2,
    Pending = 3,
    Closed = 4,
}
```

for the string based enums,  I can create a select field easily with the `Object.entries<T>().map()` like so.

```
<SelectField>
    {Object.entries<ProjectType>(ProjectType).map(([en, type]) => {
           return (<option value={en}>{type}</option>)                                            
    })} </SelectField>
```

But,  if I'm doing this on a number based enum,  `Object.entries<T>(enum).map()` gives me ALL the entries for the enum, both the string and the related number,  so the select field would show

```
0
1
2
3
4
All Projects
Active
Operational
Pending
Closed
```

As a result,  I have to make this really ugly filter etc to get the desired result, as shown below

```
 <SelectField>
      {Object.values(ProjectStatus)
         .filter((v) => !isNaN(parseInt(v as string)))
         .filter(v => parseInt(v as string) !== ProjectStatus.AllProjects)
         .map(x => {
             return (<option value={x}>{ProjectStatus[parseInt(x as string)]}</option>)
       })} </SelectField>
```

Is there any way to do this?  I just feel that this solution that I am using now to get the desired result is pretty clanky and likely there is a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: String/non-string enums do behave differently. It's working looking at the compiled JS to see how. Click ".js" on the right to see the compiled out in this example: https://tsplay.dev/NDGG8w

Answer (score 2):

[By design](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), `enum`s have a reverse mapping (unless you initialize them with a string, as you noted). If this is undesirable, you should use a `const` object instead:

```js
const ProjectStatus = {
    AllProjects: 0,
    Active: 1,
    Operational: 2,
    Pending: 3,
    Closed: 4,
} as const; // Make all properties readonly
ProtjectStatus.Active = 2
//             ^^^^^^ Error: Cannot assign to 'Active' because it is a read-only property.
```

For most use cases, this is effectively the same as an enum, sans the reverse mapping (and slightly less generated code).

If you absolutely need an `enum`, you are stuck filtering. You might be able to improve with a helper function:

```js
function getEnumEntries<T extends {}>(e: T) {
    return Object.entries(e)
        .filter(([key, _]) => Number.isNaN(key as any - 0))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Connor, I think I should be able to use the const object version without any issues.  When would it be nescessary to use an enum vs a object version?

Comment: It's only really necessary if you want the automatic reverse mapping; otherwise, I think it's more of a preference thing. If I create an `enum`, it's usually a string type, but that's just me.